# Paypal PDT error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-pdt

I use this code to process Paypal payment data transfer (PDT):

```
            $pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; // Change to www.sandbox.paypal.com to test against sandbox
        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

        $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
        $auth_token = "my_token";
        $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        //set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
        //if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if(!$res){
            echo "HTTP ERROR";
        }else{ ...
```

But it does not work, my code tells me that the request fails, and it outputs HTTP ERROR because $res is empty.
Why?

Comment: You can change the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER value to 0 , then try again.

Comment: I tried to change it and it still doesn't work.

I tried to make the API in Postman with the same URL: www.sandbox.paypal.com with the same parameters (cmd, at, tx) and I got success response.  What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you get PDT token from sandbox account ? also refer to https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update ,please make sure the PHP environment is adequate.

Comment: Yes, the PDT token was takken from the sandbox account (it works in Postman with the same cmd, at, tx).

I also tried to use a different code and I'm getting:

`Curl error: SSL connect error
status: 0`

Thanks!!

Comment: You can refer to github.com/paypal/TLS-update ,please make sure the PHP environment is adequate